# How do I filter with the REST API in Astra DB?

Tags: rest, cassandra, datastax-astra, stargate-oss

Currently, I have problem when using Rest API in DataStax Astra.

For example data:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "Members": [
    {
      "created_at": "",
      "intfield": null,
      "id": "294",
      "role": "BA",
      "username": "Join"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "",
      "intfield": null,
      "id": "180",
      "role": "Back",
      "username": "Kien Nguyen"
    },
    {
      "created_at": "",
      "intfield": null,
      "id": "180",
      "role": "Back",
      "username": "Kien Nguyen"
    }]
}
```

Now, I want to get all Member with role Back (backend). I try using 2 api same the above image
[API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XlmYm.png)
But not success. Maybe, I passed incorrect input or input body to 2 api. I searched the forums but couldn't find a solution.

Any answer is appreciated.

Thank a lot!

Comment: Could you post the [DB ID](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/astra-faq.html#_where_do_i_find_the_database_id_and_organization_id) and the table schema from the built-in [CQL Console](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/connect/cql/connect-cqlsh.html) by running `DESCRIBE TABLE <your_keyspace_name>.<your_table_name>`? You could directly update your original question with these details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is missing crucial details including:

1. the table schema, and
2. the REST API query.

In any case, the result set you posted appears to have been "doctored" because it reports `"count": 2` but there are 3 records in the list, with `"id": "180"` duplicated.

So instead, I'm going to use an example to illustrate how to filter on a field. Here is the table I've created in my DB:

```
CREATE TABLE community.members (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name text,
    role text
)
```

It is populated with the following sample data:

```
 id  | name   | role
-----+--------+----------
 123 |  alice |  backend
 456 |    bob |  backend
 789 | charli | frontend
```

To filter based on `id = 123`, we will use the following:

- endpoint - `/api/rest/v2/keyspaces/community/members`
- filter - `where={"id": {"$eq":123}}`

The resulting request URL for REST API call (with URL-escaped characters) is:

```
https://*.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/rest/v2/keyspaces/community/members?where=%7B%22id%22%3A%20%7B%22%24eq%22%3A123%7D%7D
```

and the response is:

```
{
  "count": 1,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "alice",
      "id": 123,
      "role": "backend"
    }
  ]
}
```

If I try to filter with `role = 'backend'` (or `where={"role": {"$eq":"backend"}}`), this REST API call:

```
https://*.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/rest/v2/keyspaces/community/members?where=%7B%22role%22%3A%20%7B%22%24eq%22%3A%22backend%22%7D%7D
```

will return an error `400` because `role` is not the partition key so we can't filter on it:

```
{
  "description": "Bad request: org.apache.cassandra.stargate.exceptions.InvalidRequestException: \
    Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have \
    unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the \
    performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING",
  "code": 400
}
```

The workaround is to index the `role` column so we can filter on it:

```
CREATE INDEX ON community.members (role);
```

Now we can query it with this REST API call:

```
https://*.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/rest/v2/keyspaces/community/members?where=%7B%22role%22%3A%20%7B%22%24eq%22%3A%22backend%22%7D%7D
```

to get:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "alice",
      "id": 123,
      "role": "backend"
    },
    {
      "name": "bob",
      "id": 456,
      "role": "backend"
    }
  ]
}
```

For details and a few more examples, see [Developing with the Astra DB REST API](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/develop/dev-with-rest.html). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing directly with JSON type data/payload, you could leverage the [Document API](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/develop/dev-with-doc.html#_read_with_where) as opposed to the REST API.

Here is how one would achieve this with JSON/Document API,

```
curl -L -X  GET 'https://$ASTRA_CLUSTER_ID-$ASTRA_REGION.apps.astra.datastax.com/api/rest/v2/namespaces/myworld/collections/members?where=\{"role":\{"$eq":"Back"\}\}' \
--header "X-Cassandra-Token: $ASTRA_DB_APPLICATION_TOKEN" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

where, I've assumed `myworld` as the namespace and `members` as the collection name.

In case if you update your original question with the actual table schema and want other directions using other APIs, I'll update my answer accordingly. Cheers.

**Bonus**:
You can find the Postman collection resources [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra-serverless/docs/develop/tooling.html#postman-resources) which contain examples from all available APIs and this resource will be kept updated with latest information all the time.